# How can I place a substring anywhere in a string someway that it doesn't interfere with the regex?

Tags: regex

Imagine I have a really complex regex to match dices (like, 2 lines wide).

For the sake of simplicity, here I will use `^\d*d\d*([+-]\d+)?$` as an example (so it would match `2d20+1` and `d+7` for example).

Now, I want to be able to put in a placeholder `"<value>"` for future replacement anywhere on the string and I want it to still match (for example, `2d<value>+1` or `d+<value>`, such as afterwards I can replace it like `"2d<value>+1".replace("<value>", 1)`). Is there any way to achieve this without any kind of pre-processing (such as replacing `"<value>"` with `""`)? I want to place this pattern in a JSON schema to validate it against this string, such as I know if the text is valid or not beforehand. I already have the regex to validate the entire text (which is already incredibly complex),

Edit: I don't want to ignore something in a specific point using .* to match the rest, I just want that specifically the string `"<value>"` anywhere has no interference in the match, so I could write `6d3<value>6-<value>4` and it would match `6d3<value>6-<value>4`

Test cases:

[For the simplest case](https://regex101.com/r/QBnXjv/1) (from here I can figure out everything else on my own)

```
^\d*d\d*([+-]\d+)?$
```

`""` -> does not match

`"<value>d<value>2<value>0+<value>"` -> does match (it doesn't)

`"2d20+1"` -> does match

`"2d<value>+1"` -> does match (it doesn't)

`"<value>d10+1"` -> does match (it doesn't)

`"d"` -> does match

`"d<value>"` -> does match (it doesn't)

[For my actual case](https://regex101.com/r/P2Jmn6/1):

```
^[+-]?(?:\([+-]?)*(?:(?:\d*d\d*(?:(?:km(?![^d]*(?:e|km))|k(?![^d]*(?:e|k(?:[^m]|$)))|ei(?![^d]*(?:ei|k))|e(?![^d]*(?:e(?:[^i]|$)|k))|(([<>])\2)(?![^d]*\1)|([+\-*\/%])\3)\d*)*|\d+|f\d*)\)*(?:$|[+\-*\/%](?=[\ddf(]))(?:\([+-]?)*)+$
```

`""` -> does not match

`"d20+5"` -> does match

`"d20+f5+4d10k5+5d20km10k5"` -> does match

`"d20++5/f5+f-4d10k5--5+5d20ei10"` -> does match

`"<value_1>d20++<value_2>-<abs_1>*<math_<abs_1>-2>"` -> does match (it doesn't)

`"1<value_1>d20**2<value_2>-<abs_1>*<math_<value_10>-2>"` -> does match (it doesn't)

`"1d20e<value_1>i10-1d20ek<value_1>m10"` -> does match

Comment: What can <value> be?

Comment: @Thefourthbird literally the string <value>

Comment: Yes it's possible. What engine are you using ?

Comment: `^(?:V?\d?)*d(?:V?\d?)*V*([+-]V*(?:\dV*)+)?$`

https://regex101.com/r/8HVCfK/1  Since this isn't a duplicate, how about opening this back up  ? Or does everything have to be a duplicate ?

Comment: @sln well, this works, it's pretty ugly, but I don't think there would be any other way. can you please make it as an answer?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew as far as I know, there is no pre-processing in their answer, and my question definitely isn't a duplicate of that one, so would you please be so kind to reopen this question?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew okay, I edited the question. Is it now clear enough to be reopened?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew done, all the test cases are now in the actual body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the ***simple*** case translation to inject a variable,
(called V) allowed anywhere, and as many times between all the other syntax.
It must follow the rules where cluster groups are placed around quantified items
to include the quantified variable *`V?`* (zero or one) and the singular digit `\d`.

Basically covering all in-between legitimate places.
There needs to be a slight rewrite, but the sub-patterns are typical and can
be gleaned from the example below.

Typically *`\d*`* is replaced with *`(?:V?\d?)*`* and
*`\d+`* is replaced with *`(?:V*\d)*`*.
And always lead a segment with the *Variable*.

Its a good idea to start construction with simple variables at first.
It's called *`V`* in the first template. to be replaced by a *`<string>`* later.

```
^(?:V?\d?)*d(?:V?\d?)*V*([+-](?:V*\d)*V*)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dDmIuh/1

```
^
(?: V? \d? )*
d
(?: V? \d? )*
V*
(                             # (1 start)
   [+-]
   (?: V* \d )*
   V*
)?                            # (1 end)
$
```

Then it is a simple matter to replace the variable *`V`* with *`(?:<value>)`*
The cluster group needs to be surrounding the variable since it is now a variable with
length greater than 1.

```
^(?:(?:<value>)?\d?)*d(?:(?:<value>)?\d?)*(?:<value>)*([+-](?:(?:<value>)*\d)*(?:<value>)*)?$
```

The test cases for this:  https://regex101.com/r/pWFBgo/1

```
^
(?:
   (?: <value> )?
   \d? 
)*
d
(?:
   (?: <value> )?
   \d? 
)*
(?: <value> )*
(                             # (1 start)
   [+-]
   (?:
      (?: <value> )*
      \d
   )*
   (?: <value> )*
)?                            # (1 end)
$
```

Comment: "`\d+` is replaced with `(?:V*\d)*`" won't `(?:V*\d)*` also match `""`, which is undesirable for `"\d+"`?

Comment: @Semanual  Yeah, you can see from your desired original regex `^\d*d\d*([+-]\d+)?$` that it requires a \d in this part here `([+-]\d+)?` within the optional group `()?`. The transposition is this _`([+-](?:V*\d)+V*)?`_ If you look closely a `\d` is required here. In one of the test cases it has to match `-V` at the end without a `\d` in the target. That would in essence equate to `([+-]\d*)?` So it was modified. You can indeed go back to a `\d+` here by just replacing the quantifier to `+` ~ `([+-](?:V*\d)+V*)?` but it won't match `-V` or `+V`

Comment: @Semanual Also if you have multiple variables, the `V` can be replaced with `(?:V|V2|V3)` as needed. I've glanced at the _real_ regex in a formatted way to see what you're trying to do if you need more advice, let me know.

Comment: @Semanual If you want to keep it the way it is now `\d*` then that part of the regex can be rewritten as `([+-](?:V?\d?)*)?` and tests https://regex101.com/r/RrMixy/1

Comment: okay, thanks for the clarification there; you said you glanced the real regex formatted, how do you format them? regex reading for me were always an absolute nightmare

Comment: @Semanual https://imgur.com/jno8SuU
Use https://regexformat.com app - edit, reformat, edit, compress and test the regex. The top "Input" window is the master controller, but you can just paste into the bottom "Output" window tabs as well and press the up and down loop toolbar button to format the current contents of the Output window. Like an inline reformat.
Many tools available in this app. Email support@regexformat.com  c/o _sln_ and I will send you a permanent free key. The initial install is a trial version.

Comment: sorry, what exactly should I write and who to? and... they seem to be pretty angry at SO users for some reason I don't understand, even asking for an affidavit signage... I don't know if this is legally safe

Comment: @Semanual I contacted them about this. They said it was never meant to ban users, and was a mistake. The ban was lifted. And it appears their website confirms this. If you still want a key, install the app then email support attn:SLN which will be forwarded to me.